# macOs Swift Command Line App crashes on Task statement

Tags: swift, macos, task

I am trying a simple exercise to demonstrate using async/await in Swift and, best that I can isolate, the app crashes when executing the Task statement.  I have tried catching the exception on-throw and on-catch and the call stack does not provide any additional insight into the issue.  The error is on Thread 1:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

My theory is that the COMMAND LINE template does not support Task in this simple form.

```
//
//  main.swift
//

import Foundation

struct User {
    var username: String
    var movies = [Movie]()
}

struct Movie {
    var title: String
    var rating: Double?
}

class ManagerUsingAsync {
    func getUsers() async throws -> [User] {
        let allIsGood = true // Bool.random()

        if allIsGood {
            let users = ["mary", "casey", "theo", "dick"].map { User(username: $0) }
             return users
        } else {
            throw URLError(.cannotConnectToHost)
        }
    }

    func getUsersMovies(username: String) async throws -> [Movie] {
        let allIsGood = true // Bool.random()

        if allIsGood {
            let movies = ["breaking away", "diner", "the great escape"].map { Movie(title: $0) }
            return movies
        } else {
            throw URLError(.cannotCreateFile)
        }
    }

    func getMovieRating(title: String) async -> Double? {
        let allIsGood = true // Bool.random()

        if allIsGood {
            return Double.random(in: 1...10)
        }

        return nil
    }
}



func testAsync() async -> [User] {
    var _users = [User]()
    let manager = ManagerUsingAsync()

    do {
        _users = try await manager.getUsers()
        for var user in _users {
            user.movies = try await manager.getUsersMovies(username: user.username)
            for var movie in user.movies {
                movie.rating = await manager.getMovieRating(title: movie.title)
            }
        }

    } catch (let error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return _users
}

print("TEST ASYNC/AWAIT...")

Task {
    let users = await testAsync()
    for user in users {
        print( "Username: \(user.username) Movies: \(user.movies)" )
    }
}
```

Comment: Runs fine in my tests (dump into file; run `swift main.swift`). How precisely are you testing this?

Comment: By "fine" I mean it outputs an empty list for each user, as expected. `for var user in _users` doesn't mean what you seem to think it means. It makes a copy of each User, modifies that, and then throws it away. But it shouldn't crash. Is this really the exact code you're testing?

Comment: @RobNapier - this is cut-n-paste of main.swift.  I am pressing the RUN button or using %R.  Nothing fancy.  The functionality is intentionally trivial just to try Task in a cmd line app.   It is a pot of tutorial code using closures.

Comment: When I ran this the way you describe, it just prints "TEST ASYNC/AWAIT...", because the program terminates before the Task completes. (There's nothing here waiting on the Task to keep the program alive.) I can't reproduce this crash on two machines so far. Xcode 14.2. And I wouldn't expect a crash, so it feels like something else is going on here. You might try my original approach; put it in a file and run it with `swift main.swift`

Comment: See also: https://swiftfiddle.com/fzclgiwza5g5vfp3bcqb33tnru

Comment: @RobNapier . thanks for the swift-fiddle.  that does not crash.  now my question is why does it crash on me in Xcode -> Run.   [ed note: i just now ran the file from command line as "swift main.swift" and it throws a stack full of exception and suggests that I report a bug.].  Is is possible my version of macos or xcode?  my macbook is locked-down by corp (macos 11.6 xcode 13.2.1)
(newline)
TEST ASYNC/AWAIT...
Please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project and the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
...

Comment: I'm sure it's a compiler bug (particularly since it's a fairly old version of Swift at this point). Top-level statements are a particularly buggy part of Swift. Using Swift as a pure scripting language still isn't its major use case and the bugs take a long time to get fixed. Sometimes you can improve things by putting all your code into a func (or even a struct), and then calling that, so there's only one top-level statement.

Comment: @RobNapier running as "swift main.swift" from a Terminal session, i get a crash (cannot share the stack dump in comments):  zsh: segmentation fault  swift main.swift

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently this is somehow related to how my corporate MacBook is locked-down.  I cannot figure this out in deeper detail, but the same code works fine (as did for @RobNapier as shared in the comments) on my personal MacBook.

Not sure if this Q should be withdrawn, but there is something to be learned about corporate MDM impact on developers (not the first time).  FWIW -- My corp MacBook is managed by JAMF.